# Updating non-JSF form

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a situation where I am suppose to submit a user's payment details to my payment gateway partner.

For this I have a separate non JSF form with hidden values as parameters to be passed.

```
<form id="hiddenForm" action="#{checkoutBean.payuAction}" method="post" name="payuForm">

                        <p:outputPanel id="hiddenPanel">
                        <h:inputHidden id="hash" value="#{checkoutBean.hash}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="txnid" value="#{checkoutBean.txnid}"/>

                        <h:inputHidden id="amount" value="#{checkoutBean.totoalAmount}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="firstname" value="#{checkoutBean.firstname}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="email" value="#{checkoutBean.email}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="phone" value="#{checkoutBean.phone}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="productinfo" value="#{checkoutBean.productInfo}"/>
                        <h:inputHidden id="surl" value="#{checkoutBean.sURL}" />
                        <h:inputHidden id="furl" value="#{checkoutBean.fURL}"/>
                        </p:outputPanel>
    </form>
```

The above hidden values are generated using ajax at the last step in a wizard (primefaces). The ajax call is happening but I am unable to update the non JSF form. The values are null.

```
<p:commandButton value="Confirm" actionListener="#{checkoutBean.initPayu}" onsuccess="submitPayuForm()" update=":hiddenForm:hiddenPanel" />
```

The above button is in a `<h:form>.`

Now i believe that it is not possible to update non JSF components from JSF components. But I just can't figure out how to tackle this scenario.

Any ideas on how I can tackle this problem?

Using : JSF 2 , Primefaces 3.3

**Thanks a ton in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

Since your form is not a JSF component you don't need to append its id to ids of your JSF components (`:hiddenForm:hiddenPanel`).

In other words, try something like this:

```
<p:commandButton ... update="hiddenPanel" />
```

Comment: That doesn't work.

javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "hiddenPanel" referenced from "wizForm:j_idt62".

Comment: Akshat, carefully read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier/8644762#8644762 and then look in the generated HTML source. I guess that you actually need `update=":hiddenPanel"`.

Comment: Thanks man. The link explains it all. I had started to believe that non JSF forms cannot be updated by JSF components. 
Can you just write a 2 line answer with that link, I'll accept it as an answer.

Cheers!